# Trying to order bar graph in plotly but it's only sorting some of graph

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

So I'm using the shiny widget, selectbox, to filter by type of organizations and it displays a bar graph for each type of organization. The bar graph has the name of the organization on the y-axis and the number on the x-axis. Here is my coding to sort the graph:

```
df$abbrv <- factor(
  df$abbrv,
  levels = unique(df$abbrv)[order(df$number, decreasing = FALSE)]
)
```

And here is my code for creating the bar graph:

```
plot_ly(
  x = df$number,
  y = df$abbrv,
  type = 'bar',
  text = ifelse(nchar(df$name) > 20, df$name, "")
) %>% 
layout(margin = list(l = 150))
```

The `df$abbrv` is a column in my data frame that has the abbreviations of some organization names if the name is too long.

But yeah, for some reason the bar graph shows up for all of the graphs except 2 of them. Two of the bar graphs aren't sorted and it look likes this:

[image]

The dataframe that contains the data from the bar above:

```
structure(list(entity_name = c("KDDI", "T-Mobile, Deutsche Telecom", 
"AT&T", "AT&T", "KT Corp.", "TerraCom & YourTel", "Vodafone", 
"Three", "Bell"), year = c(2006, 2006, 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2017, 2017
), type_org = c("telecoms", "telecoms", "telecoms", "telecoms", 
"telecoms", "telecoms", "telecoms", "telecoms", "telecoms"), 
    records_lost = c(4000000L, 17000000L, 100000L, 100000L, 8700000L, 180000L, 
    2000000L, 200000L, 1900000L), 
  abbreviation = structure(c(6L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 
    3L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("AT&T", "KT Corp.", "Vodafone", "Bell", 
    "Three", "KDDI", "TerraCom & YourTel", "T-DT"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("entity_name", 
"alt_name", "description", "year", "type_org", "leak_method", 
"interesting", "records_lost", "data_sensitivity", "source_1", 
"source_2", "source_3", "source_name", "abbreviation"), row.names = c(NA, 
9L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

The dataframe that contains the data from the bar above:

```
structure(list(entity_name = c("US Dept of Defense", "US National Guard", 
"US Military", "US Military", "US Army", "Stratfor", "Tricare"
), year = c(2009, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011), type_org = c("military", 
"military", "military", "military", "military", "military", "military"
), records_lost = c(72000L, 130000L, 76000000L, 300000L, 50000L, 900000L, 4900000L), abbreviation = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("Stratfor", "US Dept of Defense", 
"US National Guard", "US Army", "Tricare", "US Military"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("entity_name", 
"alt_name", "description", "year", "type_org", "leak_method", 
"interesting", "records_lost", "data_sensitivity", "source_1", 
"source_2", "source_3", "source_name", "abbreviation"), row.names = c(NA, 
7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? It's weird that it works for all of the types except two of them. I did try using dplyr and doing the `arrange()` function, but that doesn't work when I plot it.

Comment: Please, could you share your `df` dataset ? I made several trials, but cannot replicate your problem.

Comment: Here is the name column for the df that doesn't sort the bar graph:
name                                  number
US Dept of Defense           72k
US National Guard             130k
US Military                          76M
US Army                             50k 
Stratfor                                900k
Tricare                                 4.9M
And the abbreviation column is the same as the name since the character isn't longer than 20

Comment: Actually I edited my main post and put in the df for the two bar graphs!

Comment: The best way to share a dataset is to copy and paste the output of `dput(df)` into your question. It will be easier to help you. Thank you.

Comment: Okay I put it on there